# Existence of quantum computer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer

At time there are talks about [quantum computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computers) and lot of talks and discussion on its exponential speed. But studying in some more details it makes reference to "Heisenberg uncertainty principle", which simply says that either position or momentum can be calculated for any electron. If we already know the limitation, then in which direction this research is going?

Comment: I am not at all bothered about these up/down votes..if someone can help me with the very right pin point answer please write it in a line and I will search the rest myself !!

Comment: Do you have a specific question other than "in what direction is this research going"?

Comment: @ChrisFerrie: I am willing to know that if it is not going to be what it is expected to be than why I see people working on it..I have read articles on error correcting code for quantum computers even. Is the effort worthwhile ?? what is the ray of hope ?

Comment: Are you trying to ask what effect the uncertainty principle has on quantum computing? Or maybe what limitations the uncertainty principle places on quantum computation?

Comment: The classical version of the HUP applies only to infinite-dimensional systems which excludes quantum computers. QCs do encounter non-commuting dynamical variables (which lie at the heart of the HUP) and use them in exactly (some of) the ways that set them apart form classical computers. If it is references you want, try the wikipedia article. If it is a helpful answer you want, ask a helpful question.

Comment: @PankajSejwal I think the reason you're getting downvotes is because your question is wrong. The Heisenberg principle is *not* a problem for quantum computing, and is no threat to the validity of QC research. The problem, which error-correcting codes (as you mention you've read about) are to address, is a different aspect of quantum mechanics called "decoherence." However, the fact that there exists decoherence is similarly not a no-go disproof of QC.

Comment: @above all: Please forgive me if my question is not very right but being not from physics but in softwares..I find this place good enough to get very right answers from people who are into it. "Heisenberg is not a problem" - thanks for telling me that!!!- I have never seen a comment as clear in any article.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34764/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quantum Computers can process information in a different way then classical computers the main isuues is how to use classical input to "convince" the qbit to process what we are asking and then give an answer that we can use in a positive way. Research is progressing towards a quantum level interface that can account for decoherence between the information we give and a understandable answer coming out.

In other words the language barrier between classical people and quantum interpretation. There is no technical limitation to QC's at this time only a limit of our ability to minipulate qbit
s the do What we want.

http://www.cra.org/ccc/docs/init/Quantum_Computing.pdf is a PDF document link to the currently imposed limitations of quantum computers.

Comment: Need to point out I am not an expert on quantum computers. This is the limited understanding of a very complex interaction I can not claim to know with all certainty the current "level" of research.